# Keycloak conflict (core and adapter)

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, keycloak

When trying to run my webapplication in both an embedded jetty (locally) and a 'normal' jetty instance (remotely), I think I encounter some class collision.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.keycloak.adapters.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext
```

The class `KeycloakSecurityContext` is both defined in the `keycloak-jetty-adapter` dependency and in the `keycloak-core` dependency in my project. (same version, 3.4.3 Final)

I've tried using scope 'provided' on the adapter or excluding the keycloak-core dependency from my adapter, but to no effect.
Any suggestions how to handle this combination?

Comment: Describe your setup of jetty home/base, and/or how you setup your embedded-jetty.

Comment: I guess your application should act as a Keycloak client? Why do you need to add the `keycloak-core` dependency, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues with Keycloak. You need to make sure that libraries are not duplicated.

1. You download from Keycloak the adapters and place them under tomcat/lib in tomcat/wildfly.
2. In pom.xml you need to specify the  tag without versions. This will make sure that "dependencies that are required for compiling the project code, but that will be provided at runtime by a container running the code".
3. (For IntelliJ) To make sure that your project can import Keycloak specific classes you need add them into your project. So CTRL+Shift+Alt+S -> under libraries you need to add the same jars you added at point 1.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add the scope provided on the keycloak-core maven dependency. It corrected the error.